# Creating a new table from another make it read-only in PGadmin interface

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

On PostgreSQL 11, I've created a new table from another, using a subquery :

`CREATE TABLE table2 AS (SELECT * FROM table1)`

As a result, table2 is created, but each column is in read-only mode within the PGadmin interface.

--EDIT--

To answer to Vérace's comment, i add screenshots of my tables (I use PGadmin). As you can see, Table2's columns have a locker in their name. I can update a value with an SQL Query, but not with PGadmin interface. So, it's a PGadmin problem... !

TABLE 1
[image: Table1]

TABLE 2
[image]

Comment: What makes you say that table2 is read-only? Once you've created table2, it **is** totally independent of table1! À+...

Comment: All I can think of is that there's some PGAdmin4 setting that does this? Or maybe you have some strange setting in one of your .conf files? Can you issue this command using the psql CLI tool? `CREATE TABLE table3 AS SELECT * FROM table1;`. Then check to see if you can INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE? What you describe in your question is **not** normal behaviour! Or maybe there's a permissions issue - same user for issuing the command as for looking at the table in PGAdmin4?

Comment: Creating the table with psql makes no difference : I can't edit the table within PGadmin interface, but I can with a SQL update query. It should be something soft-locked in PGadmin... It could be a permission issue : the database is on a distant server, and 2 users have rights on the table (+ postgres). I'm connected as postgres, so I should have all the rights

Comment: I don't use pgAdmin, but from other similar questions I recall that pgAdmin requires the table to have a primary key in order to be "editable" - but you can always change the table's data using DML statements manually.

Comment: Table 1 and Table 2 are exactly the same, and have both a PK ; nevertheless, the first is editable, not the second. I use PGadmin to work on a database with a friend who doesn't know SQL. I want him to be able to edit data from PGAdmin interface. That's so strange, and I can't find anything on the internet about that

Comment: If you created `table2` with the code shown in your question, it will **not** have a primary key

Comment: oh sorry, i get it, indeed, table2 doesn't have PK. And you're perfectly right : setting a Primary Key to table2 make it editable. Thank you very much ! Do you want to post it as an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a table by using following query

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS (SELECT * FROM table1)
```

`table2` is created but the sequences and constraints are not copied from  `table1`. Due to this reason columns became read only mode. You can insert the data inside the read only columns by an `insert` statement, but not by UI of PgAdmin4. By creating constraints, mainly primary key, you can change read only mode to editable columns and then you can edit the columns by UI of PgAdmin4.